# Why my SQLLiteDatabase is not executing Update?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-update, android-sqlite

I have table named 'Allocated_Stock', this table is as follows:

```
Create Table Allocated_Stock (Store_Id string not null,Item_Id string not null,
Vehicle_Id string not null, AllocatedDate date not null,Item_Qty decimal not null,

PRIMARY KEY (Store_Id, Item_Id),
FOREIGN KEY (Store_Id) REFERENCES Store (Store_Id),
FOREIGN KEY (Item_Id) REFERENCES Item (Item_Id),
FOREIGN KEY (Vehicle_Id) REFERENCES Vehicle (Vehicle_Id));
```

And when I update I use

```
String where = "Store_Id='ST001' And Item_Id = 'IM001' And Vehicle_Id = 'V0001' And AllocatedDate = '2014-08-08'";

ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
newValues.put(Store_Id, "S001");
newValues.put(Item_Id, "I001");
newValues.put(Vehicle_Id, "V001");
newValues.put(AllocatedDate, "2014-08-08");
newValues.put(Item_Qty, 550);

DBSchema.obj.updateRecord(newValues, TableName, where)
```

*the following is a different class*

```
private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper; //which extends SqlLiteHelper
private SQLiteDatabase db;

myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

public boolean updateRecord(ContentValues Content, String TableName,String Where ) {

            // Insert it into the database.
            try
            {

                return db.update(TableName, Content, Where, null) != 0;
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("GET SAMPLE VALUE"+e);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Whenever I try to update, I get an error, but firstly I couldn't catch the error. Second of all why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLiteDatabase.update() returns number of rows affected. So,
in your case, no rows were affected (most probably because of your WHERE clause)

```
       int result = 0;
        try{
         result = db.update("alarms", values,  keyId+" = ? " ,new String[]{row});
        Log.d("result", ""+result);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SYstem.out.println("number of row affected :" + result );
```

Comment: actually I have retrieve records from this where clause

Comment: is your problem Solved #Gayan1991

Comment: no its not working with code.. i have tried separately in sqlitedatabasebrowser and it worked with that engine.. it's just doesn't work with code

Comment: this.db.update(ENTRY_TABLE, args, ("message = ? and Field1 =? and Field2 =? and username = "+user), new String[] {og});

Answer (score 1):

Your where clause is not formed correctly. fix it. String should be concatenated to form the where clause with all the conditions.

```
String where = Store_Id='ST001' And Item_Id = 'IM001' And Vehicle_Id = 'V0001' And AllocatedDate = '2014-08-08';
```

should be something like below

```
String where = Store_Id + "='ST001' And " + Item_Id +  "= 'IM001' And " + Vehicle_Id + "= 'V0001' And " + AllocatedDate + " = '2014-08-08';"
```

Comment: actually it was my mistake when i post this